# Is there any way to use sap.m.PlanningCalendar in a custom way?

Tags: sapui5

I am exploring on sap.m.PlanningCalendar. I notice that there are some interval types for the calendar which is of type sap.ui.unified.CalendarIntervalType which will be an Hour,Day,Month. My requirement is I have some concept where I need to show  some periods of certain amount of time  or days. For example , instead of Jan , Feb etc. I need to show Period 1 , Period 2 , etc. where period 1 will be from March 12th to May 1st or it can be of 3 - 4 Months. Is there any way to achieve this by extending the control or any ?

Here is an image of planningCalendar
[image]

Here I need to change the months to my Periods and the appointments should fall in to the respective periods.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

there is event [intervalSelect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jzw3.png) with startDate and endDate. Check [here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.PlanningCalendar).

Have a nice Day